C++ - Use a parent class to prevent derivative classes from defining constructors?
I don't know if what I'm proposing in this question is a bad idea or not or even reasonable to ask because I don't have enough experience with C++ to know any better, but I digress for the sake of getting to the point of this post.
I'm currently working on a rudimentary game engine in cooperation with the SDL2 framework for my own personal small-scale game projects. This is important to note because my question makes a clear distinction between engine classes and front-end classes. The only difference relevant to this question is that front-end classes exist on a per-project basis and are aware of all engine classes whereas engine classes are the same set of classes for every project and are therefore not aware of any specific front-end classes that may exist.
I have two engine classes: Entity and EntityFactory<typename T> (where of course T is only ever intended to be Entity or some derivative of Entity). The idea for the front-end developer is that they make a class like Man that derives from Entity, that Man class ONLY being constructable via a call to new Man() in EntityFactory<Man>. To achieve construction exclusivity as I described, I could make the default Entity constructor private and then make EntityFactory<typename T> a friend of Entity, but then Man ALSO needs to let EntityFactory<typename T> be his friend (or at least let EntityFactory<Man> be his friend). That part I don't mind so much since the program will not compile UNTIL Man becomes a friend of EntityFactory<typename T>, the problem I have is that Man can define any constructors he wants and then other front-end classes can construct a Man without doing so through EntityFactory<Man>. None of this would be a problem if the design didn't require new types of Entity to be derived from Entity, but I really like that about the design and I don't want it to change.
How can I, by ONLY editing engine classes Entity and EntityFactory<typename T>, make sure classes like Man cannot define ANY new constructors that would allow Man to be constructed by anything other than a call to new Man() in EntityFactory<Man>? CAN this even be done?
If what I'm asking for IS in fact impossible, I would appreciate answers as to how to achieve the concept of 'Factory that makes mostly the same thing but front-end classes can define slight variations of the thing that the factory makes'.
Many thanks for reading! :)

A class itself defined/manages whether it has any ctors or not. Other classes has no say in it. Even if you inherit ctors the derive class have to do it by writing a using declaration.

That makes sense to me and was kind of expected, but is nonetheless disappointing. I have updated my answer in response to this comment looking for alternative solutions to my concept. So long as I get a solution of 'Factory that makes mostly the same thing but front-end classes can define slight variations of the thing that the factory makes', I don't mind how it is achieved.

Instead of allowing the user to derive from entity, make him only able to derive a component of it, ie : the entity will have an abstract Draw2D component, and he can construct that in any way that he wants, but he cannot construct or derive entity and without entity his Draw2D component has no use, and you control how entity is constructed.

good read Game Programming Design Patterns

The final specifier?

Disclaimer: I'm not saying this is good design. It's an answer to the question.
If you are willing to change EntityFactory to be a plain class instead of a class template, you could give EntityFactory sole access to a hidden constructor in Entity and thereby prevent anyone from deriving from Entity and provide constructors making them constructible without using EntityFactory.
Example:
class EntityFactory;

class Entity {
private:   
    class hidden_tag_t {
        constexpr hidden_tag_t() = default;
        friend Entity;
    };
    static inline constexpr hidden_tag_t hidden_tag{};

    friend EntityFactory; // EntityFactory has access to the hidden tag

public:
    Entity(const Entity&) = delete;

    // ctor unusable for everyone but EntityFactory:
    constexpr explicit Entity(hidden_tag_t) {}

    virtual ~Entity() = default;
};

class EntityFactory final {
public:
    template<class T>
    std::unique_ptr<T> create() {
        // using the hidden tag:
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(Entity::hidden_tag));
    }
};

class Man : public Entity {
public:
    // in order to derive from Entity, the user must define a constructor that
    // forwards to Entity:
    template<class T>
        requires (not std::derived_from<T, Entity>)
    Man(T&& t) : Entity(std::forward<T>(t)) {}
};

Example usage:
int main() {
    EntityFactory ef;
    auto man = ef.create<Man>();
}

This does however not prevent a writer of Man from instantiating other Entity based classes using the tag in its constructor, but that may be an ok compromise:
    template<class T>
        requires (not std::derived_from<T, Entity>)
    Man(T&& t) : Entity(std::forward<T>(t)) {
        Woman w(t); // Woman is here derived from Entity too
    }


This could of course be simplified further by moving the factory function into Entity:
class Entity {
private:   
    class hidden_tag_t {
        constexpr hidden_tag_t() = default;
        friend Entity;
    };
    static inline constexpr hidden_tag_t hidden_tag{};

public:
    template<class T>
    static std::unique_ptr<T> create() {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(hidden_tag));
    }

    Entity(const Entity&) = delete;

    constexpr explicit Entity(hidden_tag_t) {}

    virtual ~Entity() = default;
};

int main() {
    auto man = Entity::create<Man>();
}


You can control how/where the constructor is called by requiring arguments (possibly dummy) that are available only in certain contexts.
For example, you can require an object of type CreatedInFactory<T> to be passed, while CreatedInFactory can be created only in a corresponding factory. For example like this:
//engine code

class Entity {};

template<typename T>
class EntityFactory;

template<typename T>
class CreatedInFactory {
    private:
    CreatedInFactory() {}
    friend class EntityFactory<T>;
};

template<typename T>
class EntityOf : public Entity {
    public:
    EntityOf(CreatedInFactory<T>) {}
};

template<typename T>
class EntityFactory {
    public:
    T* make() {
        return new T(CreatedInFactory<T>());
    }
};

//user code

class Man : public EntityOf<Man> {
    public:
    //Man() {} //fail: EntityOf<Man> not properly constructed
    Man(CreatedInFactory<Man> c) : EntityOf<Man>(c) {}
};

int main() {
    EntityFactory<Man> factory;
    Man* entity1 = factory.make(); //ok
    //Man* entity2 = new Man(CreatedInFactory<Man>()); //fail: CreatedInFactory constructor is private
}

It is not entirely bullet-proof, but it will make the user that much harder to construct your classes in a way you do not want them to be constructed.
One possible walkaround is to call additional new Man within the constructor of Man while already having the CreatedInFactory<T> object available.

On a completely different topic - since you are talking about games and entities, have you heard about the Entity Component System paradigm? It is a major departure from traditional OOP, but it may fit what you are doing.
